# Mapping: foreach binding work only the first time

Tags: foreach, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following snippet *JQuery* inside an HTML file:

```
$.getJSON("/events/", function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The code is executed when, for example, the user presses a button and returns JSON like:

```
{"Events":[{"Name":"Event1"},{"Name":"Event2"},{"Name":"Event3"}]}
```

This result is linked (using *KnockoutJS*) to:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Events">
    <li><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine with **the first call** to `$.GetJSON`. I get what I want, which is (browser output):

- **Event1**
- **Event2**
- **Event3**

But in subsequent calls to "$. GetJSON" I get the following error in *Firebug*:

`NotFoundError: Node was not found.
containerNode.insertBefore(nodeToInsert, insertAfterNode.nextSibling);`

And I get no list item.

What I can be doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Knockout is to handle the interaction between your view and view model. In this case, you're trying to update a list of events in response to a button click. The button click should be linked to a function in your view model, while the list should be linked to an observable array that's updated when you click the button. I've put this together in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/uZb3e/ and the important parts are below:

```
<button type=button data-bind="click: updateEvents">Update</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: data.Events">
    <li><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    data: ko.mapping.fromJS({"Events":[]}),
    updateEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON("/events/", function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(newData, self.data);
        });​
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

Answer (score 1):

My friend Thomas Brattli found the solution:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'template', foreach: Events }"></ul>

<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <li><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></li>
</script>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your solution may work (using a named template), but the real problem is that you're calling `ko.applyBindings` multiple times on the same view. This isn't supported by Knockout and will inevitably cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Michael! How do you think it would be better to implement in this case?